# Detect category choice for posts with multiple categories

Tags: categories, page-template

On my single template, I wish to show other posts in that category.
Its essential that I use the route they chose, i.e. if they clicked Category 1, then Post A, if Post A is also Categorised as Category 2 and Category 3, I only want to show posts from Category 1 because that is what they originally chose.

Is this an option?
Is there a way to store some sort of global variable which I can set on my category page, then utilise on my single page?

Comment: Could you go back through your questions and accept any correct answers? a 0% acceptance rate isn't going to get you any answers =(

Comment: okay, if it'll get me an answer! Though I only accept answers where I actually get a good answer. Out of my 4 other questions, only 1 deserved the correct answer tick. Though, if it'll appease you, we're now at 100%

Comment: If it answers the question then it should be accepted, there's nothing stopping you switching if a better answer comes along

Comment: And if ti isn't good enough you should comment and explain why so the person answering can ammend the answer (maybe they misunderstood?)

Comment: Yeah, I know how it works, I've been a member of SO and other SE sites for a couple of years. Though as I don't use this one as much I tend to forget. They're done now. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
get_query_var('category-name');
```

Which will give you:

> example.com/**category/subcategory**/my_post

Which you can then put into any queries you make under `category-name`.

You can see this in action using the Monkeyman rewrite analyser plugin, by entering one of the URLs for a post and seeing the query variables it generates using those rules

Comment: Thanks for this! I should forget to mark you as correct just for the fun of it now ;-p

Comment: haha you wouldn't dare =p

Comment: Could you post more details on how to implement this? Where code goes, which template etc?